# Owner of a S3 bucket in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

When we create a bucket on AWS the default owner of the bucket is the root user. But what happens is if I create a bucket in any region except frankfurt the owner is the user like "dee" but in frankfurt its a string instead of user.

Does anybody has any idea why the behaviour is different in case of frankfurt ?

Comment: how do you create the account ? Frankfurt supports [signature version 4 only](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region) - relationship ?

Comment: Thanks,this is the actual reason . Checked here about version 4 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier and the same format string mentioned in this document is generated. In version 2 user name comes. So it justifies. Still the account is created by normal method from UI and i have an IAM user on that account.

Comment: One thing i would like to add creating bucket both from UI and s3 api this happens.